# Jest test error - Cannot find module meteor/tprzytula:remember-me

Tags: reactjs, meteor, jestjs

I am using **[meteor/tprzytula:remember-me](https://github.com/tprzytula/Meteor-Remember-Me)** package in my Meteor React app.

I also use **Jest** for test automation.

I use the RememberMe component in my Signin form (a React functional component in Meteor)

When I try running tests with Jest I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'meteor/tprzytula:remember-me' from 'imports/ui/components/signin/SigninForm.js'

Require stack:
  imports/ui/components/signin/SigninForm.js
  tests/Signin.test.js

  2 | import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
  3 | import {Accounts} from 'meteor/accounts-base';
> 4 | import RememberMe from 'meteor/tprzytula:remember-me';
    | ^
```

Here is my test code using Jest and Enzyme

*tests/Signin.test.js*

```
const wrapper = mount(<SigninForm />);
```

**Update**

I run my tests using `npm test`.  Here is my entry on package.json

*package.json*

```
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/jest --verbose --silent",
```

Also adding my `jest.config.js`. Note I commented out moduleNameMapper. It errors out either way.

*jest.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: [
    './tests/setupTests.js',
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
  ],
  modulePaths: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-meteor-stubs/lib/',
  ],
  // moduleNameMapper: {
  //   'meteor/tprzytula:remember-me': 'meteor/tprzytula:remember-me',
  //   '^(.*):(.*)$': '$1_$2',
  // },
  unmockedModulePathPatterns: [
    '/^imports\\/.*\\.jsx?$/',
    '/^node_modules/',
  ],
};
```

Is there a solution/workaround for this problem?

Comment: how do you run the tests?

Comment: I updated the question with how I run tests using `./node_modules/.bin/jest --verbose --silent` . Also added my jest config

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! Since all import in meteor that start with `meteor/` are *not* npm modules, but meteor packages, I don't think you will be able to start jest directly, without meteor. Maybe this can help: https://blog.meteor.com/real-world-unit-tests-with-meteor-and-jest-3d557e84e84a ?

Comment: If your tests can run without that meteor package, then you can try loading it only conditionally: `if (Meteor) { import RememberMe from 'meteor/tprzytula:remember-me'; }`

Comment: I agree with @ChristianFritz opinion. Jest is trying to import a Meteor package and Meteor packages aren't accessible in a non-meteor context. I believe e2e tests are your best bet in such cases.